# Making an independent RPC server with autobahn wamp (twisted)

Tags: python, wamp, twisted, rpc, autobahn

I need to create an independent class that provides an RPC server running in its own Python process using wamp and autobahn.

Following some guides found here, I managed to create this server in these classes saved into the file **rpcwampserver.py**:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunner
import multiprocessing
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Manager(ApplicationSession):

    @inlineCallbacks
    def onJoin(self, details):
        print("session ready")

        def test():
            return u'hello!'

    try:
            yield self.register(test, u'rpc.test')
            print("procedure registered")
        except Exception as e:
            print("could not register procedure: {0}".format(e))

class RPCWampServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._url = u'ws://localhost:8080/ws'
        self.real = u'realm'
        self.runner = ApplicationRunner(url=self._url, realm=self.realm,
                                        #debug=True, debug_wamp=True, debug_app=True
                                        )

    def start(self):
        self.runner.run(Manager, start_reactor=False)

class RPC_Wamp_Server:    
    def __init__(self):
        server = RPCWampServer()
        server.start()
        multi = multiprocessing.Process(target=reactor.run,args=())
        multi.start()
```

If RPC_Wamp_Server is imported directly into a file close to rpcwampserver.py the the code works fine:

```
from rpcwampserver import RPC_Wamp_Server
c=RPC_Wamp_Server()
```

#### BUT

If I use this class inside a package located in a different path, the reactor doesn't work:

```
from mymodules.wamp.rpcwampserver import RPC_Wamp_Server
c=RPC_Wamp_Server()
```

The class **RPC_Wamp_Server** is found but the initialization of the Manager seems to be skipped.

Enabling the debug (commented in the code) it appears:

```
Starting factory [...]
```

and after a while

```
Stopped factory [...]
```

---

EDIT:
Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost solved the problem

Comment: using the ip address "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" solves the problem...